# Rotating a bitmap around center on android

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

Good day, my first question here after wasting 3+ hours. I have reviewed dozens of different posts with similar questions and a small wide of answers.

I'm currently designing a function that takes a bitmap and an angle, and returns a rotated version, for my spaceship android game

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle){ 


    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.setRotate(angle, source.getWidth()/2,  source.getHeight()/2);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

}
```

i have tried several different options , mixing translate, post and pre rotate methods, but all proven unneffective. I have to admit I have limited knowledge on matrix but android developer sources seem crystal clear to me, yet any method I tried does anything regarding the pivot point. The rotation always happens but  effectively displacing my ship to other hexes

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't manage with this function so I ended up making another with same effect.

```
public void rotate(Bitmap paramBitmap, float angle, Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
{
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(x, y);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-paramBitmap.getWidth() / 2, -paramBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
    canvas.restore();

}
```

It rotates the canvas instead